# Facebook Request Dialog response contains no request_ids? What's going on?

Tags: dialog, facebook-ios-sdk

We’re using the Facebook SDK for iOS. Everything works (both auth and feed dialog etc.), except the Request Dialog; the callback function "dialogCompleteWithUrl" is getting response URLs that contain no request_ids at all! We get something like "fbconnect://success?request=177205945735026&to%5B0%5D=559849340", which effectively translates to "fbconnect://success?request=177205945735026&to[0]=559849340" if you decode the URL encoding. We checked the friend's account; there were no requests in the notification section. Can anyone please help?

Furthermore, we tested the Hackbook sample using "Send invite" menu; it did NOT work either -- it generates similar URLs with no request_ids in it.

BTW, We're using the latest Facebook iOS SDK (downloaded last week on April 20, 2012) on the latest XCode 4.3.2 using iOS 5.1 & 5.0; tests were done on both the simulator and new iPad, as well as iPhone 4. A test using http://demo.vatlab.net/RequestDialog.aspx works between the user accounts used in the iOS sdk test mentioned above.

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: How is your app configured? If it's not set up correctly in the app settings, and is just an iOS app (i.e no corresponding canvas app), the requests won't be displayed because Facebook knows about your iOS app (app store details, etc) it won't know how/where to send the user

Comment: Have you tried using the new iOS SDK?

Answer (score 0):

The docs states:

> Requests will only surface on platforms where the game has been
>   defined in the app dashboard as having a presence. So for example, if
>   an app exists on iOS and Android, but has no Canvas presence,
>   recipients will not see requests received via that app appear on the
>   desktop web version of Facebook.com.

[Facebook Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.0)